# PhoneGap and Amazon SNS

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap, amazon-sns

I am looking for a sample code to send notifications using PhoneGap and Amazon SNS (using PHP). Unfortunately, there is no plug-in for Amazon SNS.

Comment: Are you sure? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-sns.html

Comment: @5c625b7c Thanks, but it doesn't show a complete example

Comment: it has enough for you to put together a working solution.